# What are limitations of giving birth to a baby from a frozen embryo?

Tags: embryology, pregnancy

Recently the story of a woman giving birth to baby girl from an embryo frozen 24 years ago hit the news. After an in vitro fertilization the embryo was frozen on 14 October 1992(
[Article in the Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2017/dec/20/woman-gives-birth-to-baby-who-spent-24-years-as-a-frozen-embryo))

So I wonder about the limitations concerning freezing embryos. Especially the following questions came to my mind:

- How much time after the embryo has been fertilized has passed before
  he was frozen?
- How much more time after fertilization could pass before the embryo
  has to be frozen?

Comment: There are a lot of questions here. Can you narrow things down some?

Comment: As suggested by @kmm I deleted two questions.